# PDO with MSSQL resulting in zero inserted elements when written as a prepared statement

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, pdo

I have been going over this query repeatedly trying to understand why it won't work as a prepared statement when run in PDO, but seems to work fine when set up as a stored procedure. Can anyone help provide some insight into where I may be running in to trouble?

Here is the relevant PHP:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dbConn,$dbUser,$dbPass);
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
$statement = 'INSERT INTO dashboard.dashboard (studyName, respondent_id1, respondent_id2, respondent_id3, sample_provider, completion_status, loi, [endpoint]) VALUES (:studyName, :respondent_id1, :respondent_id2, :respondent_id3, :sample_provider, :completion_status, :loi, :ep);';
$result = $pdo->prepare($statement);
$arr = array('studyName' => $studyName, 'respondent_id1' => $respondent_id1, 'respondent_id2' => $respondent_id2, 'respondent_id3' => $respondent_id3, 'sample_provider' => $sample_provider, 'completion_status' => $completion_status, 'loi' => $loi, 'ep' => $endpoint);
$result->execute($arr);
```

I know I am not having issues with the database connection, as the query works with hard-coded values, just not with a prepared statement.

For reference, if I replace $statement with the following it works fine:

```
$statement = "INSERT INTO dashboard.dashboard (studyName, respondent_id1, respondent_id2, respondent_id3, sample_provider, completion_status, loi, [endpoint]) VALUES ('testingNewPush', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'provEx', 'terminate', 500, 'testing');";
```

In addition, I am receiving the following output when I var_dump($arr):

```
array(8) { ["studyName"]=> NULL ["respondent_id1"]=> string(5) "test2" ["respondent_id2"]=> string(4) "test" ["respondent_id3"]=> string(4) "test" ["sample_provider"]=> string(10) "Communicus" ["completion_status"]=> string(9) "terminate" ["loi"]=> int(600) ["ep"]=> string(3) "Age" }
```

I would really appreciate any insight into what I may be doing wrong here.

Comment: Try `bindParam()` instead http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php or `bindValue()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php to  see if that makes any difference. However and on the "very rare" occasion, the colon may need to be added in the arrays. I.e.: `array(':studyName' => $studyName.....` etc., being a slim chance but worth a shot.

Comment: check to see if error handling picks up on something. Both http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll give this a shot when I'm back at the work computer tomorrow, and let you know how it goes. I have tried the array with and without the colon, so I don't think that is the issue. I'll also check if I can see it throwing any errors here, though I believe I checked this last week and saw no errors being thrown, I'll double check. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Ok Anthony and you're welcome. We'll see if anyone else picks up on something I may not know about.

Comment: Error handling doesn't seem to be throwing anything, and I haven't had any luck with bindParam or bindValue here. The good news is that I am planning to build this in to a stored procedure to avoid any issues, but I'd still love to know what I'm doing wrong here if anyone else sees this.

Comment: Well, the only thing left that I can think of is to see if the column lengths are long enough; that may be failing silently. The variables are unknown as to where they're coming from, if from a form or not. If so and you're using a "GET" method with POST arrays (or vice-versa), then that could also be failing silently. There isn't anything else that comes to mind besides that Anthony.

Comment: Thanks again @Fred-ii- I Will keep playing with this and report back if I have any success.

Comment: Can you try : "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF" before the insert?

Comment: once had the same issue and this did the trick

Answer (score -1):

In array need to write ":"  array(':studyName' => $studyName, ':respondent_id1' => $respondent_id1)

```
$statement = 'INSERT INTO dashboard.dashboard (studyName, respondent_id1, respondent_id2, respondent_id3, sample_provider, completion_status, loi, [endpoint]) VALUES (:studyName, :respondent_id1, :respondent_id2, :respondent_id3, :sample_provider, :completion_status, :loi, :ep);';
    $result = $pdo->prepare($statement);
    $arr = array(':studyName' => $studyName, ':respondent_id1' => $respondent_id1, ':respondent_id2' => $respondent_id2, ':respondent_id3' => $respondent_id3, ':sample_provider' => $sample_provider, ':completion_status' => $completion_status, ':loi' => $loi, ':ep' => $endpoint);
    $result->execute($arr);
```